# Python - for-loop inside itertools.product()

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm having an error in my head right now.

I have a large number of variables, which can be in two states each. I want to combine them to an array and for that I've chosen itertools.product.

So basically what i need is somethin like

```
a = ["A", "a"]
b = ["B", "b"]
c = ["C", "c"]
...
result = list(itertools.product(a,b,c,...)
```

If i write a,b,c by hand it works fine, but it would be annoying to write that much.
My approach so far was to store my states in a dictionary that I updated in a loop:

```
dict = {1: ["A","a"], 2: ["B","b"], ..., 300: ["XYZ", "xyz"]}
```

and now I want to combine it

```
result = list(itertools.product([dict[i] for i in range(1,4)]))
```

now I expect something like

```
("A","B","C"),("A","B","c"),("A","b","C"),...,("a","b","c")
```

but instead I get

```
(['A', 'a'],), (['B', 'b'],), (['C', 'c'],)
```

How did that happen? And how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.product` accepts a variable number of arguments, not a list of arguments. So, just unwrap the list by putting a `*` in front of it

```
itertools.product(*[dict[i] for i in range(1,4)])
```

Comment: very useful thank you